# Match a string expect specific characters

Tags: regex, bash, perl

So I've been trying for a while now, to match a string then exclude a certain character from it.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO public.tags (created_at,
```

I want to end up with :

```
INSERT INTO tags (created_at,
```

- I want to remove the public. - but it could be any string followed by a dot.

this is what I've tried so fat with no luck:

`\.tags` which only match '.tags'

`([^\s]+)(\.tags)` which match the whole public.tags string

Comment: What do you expect to get in the end?

Comment: Maybe `s/^(.*?)\S+\.(tags).*/$1$2/`?

Comment: Probably because a) your question was unclear and b) you showed no real effort to solve it yourself. (Note: I wasn't the downvoter - I'm just guessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/\S+\.tags\b/tags/
```

or

```
s/\S+\.(?=tags\b)//
```

Comment: Yes this is it, It would be great if you explain it. thank you :)

Comment: `(?=...)` is called a forward lookahead. It checks if the current position is followed by the subpattern, but without advancing the match position from the perspective of the outside of the parens.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear. But I think you're saying that you have:

```
INSERT INTO public.tags (created_at,
```

And you want to end up with:

```
INSERT INTO tags (created_at,
```

You want to remove the `public.` - but it could be any string followed by a dot.

This seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $sql = 'INSERT INTO public.tags (created_at,';

# Use s/.../.../ - the substitution operator.
# \S - match any non-whitespace character.
# + - match one or more of the previous atom.
# \. - match a dot.
# tags - match the string 'tags'
# \b - match the end of a word
# So match a string of non-whitespace characters,
# followed by '.tags' at the end of a word.
# Replace it with 'tags'.
$sql =~ s/\S+\.tags\b/tags/;

print $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

sed can do it easily.

```
echo "INSERT INTO public.tags (created_at," | sed 's/tags//'
```

This is specific to your example, but we can easily add onto it if we need to.

Comment: I don't want to get rid of tags, I want to get rit of public. which comes before tags

Comment: `sed 's/public//'`

Comment: Public is not constant, actully the pattern is 'XYZ'.tags I want to get rid of XYZ whatever the value.

Comment: Ok.  But you didn't put that in your question.  Create a variable (i.e. `myvar="XYZ"`), and then sub that into the sed command (`sed "s/$myvar//"`).  Just make sure to use double quotes if you use a variable.